# Dúvida com o $http no AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, aplicação-web

Quando eu faço o **get**, eu o carrego em um objeto o $scope.contatos e consigo mostrá-lo em minha *View* do html.

Porém, eu só consigo acessar ele dentro dentro da minha função do `then(function(){})`, quando saio da parte na qual chamei o $http, não consigo mais acessar o $scope.contatos, onde ele consta como *undefined*.

Analisei que mesmo criando uma variável global, se associar o valor dele ao $scope.contatos dentro do meu $http também não consigo acessar o valor da variável, que também irá constar como *undefined*.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

    app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope,$http){

        $scope.contatos = [];
        $scope.nomes = [];
        var st;

        $http.get("/jsons/contatos.json").then(function(response) {

            console.log("sucesso");
            $scope.contatos = response.data.contatos;
            st = $scope.contatos;

            for(j = 0; j < $scope.contatos.length; j++){
                angular.forEach($scope.contatos[j], function(value,key){                    
                    if(key=="nome"){
                        $scope.nomes.push(value);
                    }                   
                });
            }               
        },function(response){
            console.log("erro");
        });

        console.log($scope.contatos);//aqui ele ja não funciona mais
        console.log(st);//não funciona tambem

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Como `$http.get` é assíncrono, provavelmente quando chega no código após ele (`Console.log...`) ainda não tem o retorno. Então seu código (`Console.log...`) pode estar sendo executado antes do retorno do `$http.get` e por isso imprime `undefined`.

Comment: Renan muito obrigado pela resposta, creio que é isso mesmo.

Comment: Ok @Nicholas Maestrello Agiz vou colocar uma resposta então.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o método **`$http.get`** é assíncrono, quando vai executar as linhas de código `console.log($scope.contatos);` e `console.log(st);` o método **`$http.get`** ainda não retornou, por isso imprime *undefined*.